# jQuery value of field not defined

Tags: jquery

I have a very basic form with a select field on it that can contain multiple options.

While submitting my form, I check the length and if it contains at least one value then I generate an XML string for each one of them.

```
var type = $('[name=advancedType]').val(),
    newType = type.split(','),
    typeXML;

if(newType.length > 0){
        typeXML = '<types>';
        for(var i = 0; i<newType.length; i++){
            typeXML  += '<type>';
            typeXML  += '<typeID>'+newType[i]+'</typeID>';
            typeXML  += '</type>';
        }
        typeXML += '</types>';
    }else{
        typeXML = '';   
    }
```

When type has an option selected, it works fine but when I don't pick anything, it says type is not defined.

How can I get this to work as intended? Seems so simple..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newType = (type && type.split(',')) || [];
```

Comment: Hmm, now it says `type.split` is not a function when I do select one and it works fine when I do not select one..

Comment: Use console.log before you perform the split to see what your value is for each case

Comment: `type = ($('[name=advancedType]').val()) || [],` I got it to work like that; eliminating split alltogether